# How can i edit right sidebar of "Timeless" Skin of Mediawiki?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

I want to edit the right sidebar as shown in the below image. please suggest how can I edit this sidebar.

[Right sidebar of Timeless skin Mediawiki](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2Ca5.png)

Answer (score 0):

Change `MediaWiki:Sidebar`, provided you have the appropriate permissions. Be also prepared that the syntax is somewhat different from that of normal pages. Read more in [Manual:Interface/Sidebar - MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Interface/Sidebar).